# How to send more than one value to single parameter?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to send three string "huis" to crystal report parameter 
he only work if i select one checkbox

i wanna crystal report give me what is selected on checkbox(huis)

```
 select * from Mess22 where Cont in {?@huis}
```

```vb
Dim huis As String

        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            huis = CheckBox1.Text
        End If

        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            If huis = "" Then
                huis = CheckBox2.Text
            Else
                huis = huis & "," & CheckBox2.Text
            End If
        End If

Aver5.Load("Avert5.rpt")
        Aver5.SetParameterValue("@huis", huis.ToString)
        AvF.CR2.ReportSource = Aver5
        AvF.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: 3 textboxs or 3 textbox.text strings? there is a huge difference. the latter you could easily send as an array of string. the former you could send as an array of textbox

Comment: its that huis string

Comment: Sorry, but this makes zero sense.

Comment: i edited see more codes maybe will make sense

Comment: Your question still makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Change the record selection formula to:
Cont in Split({?@huis}, ",")
This would turn the string into an array for comparison.

The other option is to design the parameter as a multi-value parameter and use the API to add the values one by one.